# NASM Assembly Programming - Incrementing an Address

Tags: assembly, nasm, increment, memory-address

I am learning the basics of assembly programming again. I am slowly working my way through [Assembly Language Step-by-Step: Programming with Linux](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470497025).

I am working on 64-bit Slackware machine (x86-x64), using NASM.

I am a little confused about what it means to increment an address. In my `bss` section, I have a `Buffer resb 4096` buffer. In the `text` section I assign the address to `esi`:

```
mov esi, Buffer
```

Later on, I `inc esi`. This appears to advance `esi` to the next byte offset. I was a little surprised - I was expecting `esi` to advance 4 bytes because it is a 32-bit register.

Can I assume that incrementing an address will always move one byte at a time? Would I use `add esi, 4` to advance 32-bits?

Do I have to explicitly ask for 4 bytes when I want to fill a 32-bit register? Something like `mov eax, DWORD [esi]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

%esi is a register.  It can contain an address, your bank account balance or anything else.  There is no way the cpu knows what kind of value it contains.  `inc` is simply an arithmetic instruction that increments the value stored in a register by 1.

So yeah, if you want to increment it by 32-bit, you have to add 4.

It's different when you do load and stores, the register you'll pick (say either %al or %eax) will indicate the size of load/store.  If there is any ambiguity or if you want to change the size of the load/store, you'll need to use the size qualifier (word/dword etc)

Comment: That actually makes what I'm doing a lot easier. I was concerned I would have to process 4 bytes at a time.